# [colors] tag synonyms

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

It's odd, but I find it funny nobody has noticed this.

The tag `[colors]` has 1042 questions under it, yet it has [no synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/colors/synonyms).

The tag `[color]` has four questions, yet it has [two synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/color/synonyms):

- `[colour] -> [color]`
- `[colours] -> [color]`

What happened here?

**Edit:** I've just added in the `[color] -> [colors]` synonym. Go vote for it.

Comment: +1, but not enough rep yet to vote :(

Comment: Some moderator will need to fix the old synonyms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And... it's done. Can't believe it took so long though...